# Moving bazel-bin symlink somewhere else?

Tags: dropbox, bazel

Is there a non-painful way to have bazel-bin symlink moved to some other location and still be able to do `bazel test` commands as usual?

The philosophical problem is that having reponame/bazel-bin puts object files in the same hierarchy as the source files.

The practical problem is that I keep my github repo synced across different machines, so having bazel-bin in the hierarchy forces my syncing tool (dropbox) to fswatch >1M files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--symlink_prefix` flag. For example, `bazel build --symlink_prefix=/tmp/somewhere_else` will create the symlinks under `/tmp/somewhere_else` and `bazel build --symlink_prefix=/` will not create any symlinks at all.

Docs are here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#build-options

Comment: Thanks, that worked for -bin and -genfiles folder, but bazel-out symlink is still getting created, filed https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3796

Comment: Yea, unfortunately that symlink seems to be hardcoded. The only option is to disable symlinks entirely with `--symlink_prefix=/`

Comment: I got a work-around -- create an unwriteable file "bazel-bin". It complains, but everything works